# In which cases Plutus compiler is producing expensive code?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract

I have heard a couple of times, that is hard to make Plutus produce non-costly code, and one should consider writing scripts on a level with Plutarch's help instead. Still, I never get real reasons and examples for this.

Only case I am aware of are problems unnecessary Scott-encoding, but I am not aware of details.

Is this problem real and still relevant? If so in which cases does one get it, and how it may be mitigated? Can it be done with an external optimization pass, like [plutonomy](https://github.com/well-typed/plutonomy) or Plutus options tweaking?